# Get finnaly sql string in Yii

Tags: php, sql, yii

I try get compile sql string, created by CdbCriteria, using config:

```
array(
...
   'db' => array(
...
      'enableProfiling' => true,
      'enableParamLogging' => true,
   ),
...
   'log' => array(
      'class' => 'CLogRouter',
      'routes' => array(
         array(
            'class' => 'CProfileLogRoute',
            'levels' => 'profile',
            'enabled' => true,
         ),
...
```

But in log i don't get finnaly sql query, just string like

```
system.db.CDbCommand.query(SELECT * FROM `tourn` `t` WHERE (:tournId > 0 AND id = :tournId) AND (:userId > 0 AND user_id = :userId) LIMIT 1. Bound with :tournId='1 OR TRUE', :userId='1')
```

How can i get compiled query? With already replaced parameters placeholder.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood what a compiled query is. The SQL you are seeking never exists as a string. That's the point of using placeholders.

Comment: hm, ok. I just come from Kohana. There you can get "compiled" sql query by Database::instance()->last_query. I thought that Yii have similar mechanism. Thanks.

Comment: That would mean that Kohana either constructed such a string (for debug purposes) or that Kohana had a potential SQL injection vulnerability. It is possible that you can log the parameters somehow, but I don't know yii or php, so I can't really help with that.

Answer (score 1):

The extension Yii-Debug-Toolbar provides you with all SQL queries for each request: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-debug-toolbar/